# Writing arraylist to textfile

Tags: java, arraylist, writetofile

I have an arraylist of class `Room` which is held in class `Hostel`, i would like to write this arraylist to a text file. What is the most efficient method of doing so?

Hostel Class

```
public class Hostel
{
    private ArrayList < Room > rooms;
}
```

Room Class

```
abstract class Room
{

public Room(int newRoomNo, boolean newRoomEnSuite, int newRoomNights, String        newRoomBooker)
    {
        roomNo = newRoomNo;
        roomEnSuite = newRoomEnSuite;
        roomBooking = "Booked";
        roomNights = newRoomNights;
        roomBooker = newRoomBooker;
    }
}
```

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Comment: Create a method that writes one room to a file passed as a parameter. Then open a file, use a `for` loop to iterate through the arraylist and write each `Room` instance, and close the file. When in doubt, use google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A one-liner from [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/)

```
FileUtils.writeLines(new File(path), list);
```

Comment: I think this is only using the `toString()` method of the lists elements.

Comment: @Stephan it isn't. There's a method that takes File and Collection

Comment: And how are the elements of the collections written?

Comment: the collection is iterated. See `IOUtils.writeLines`

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Hostel {
    public void writeRooms(ArrayList<Room> rooms){
        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.size(); i++) {
            write(rooms[i]);
        }
    }
    void write(Room room) throws IOException  {
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("FileName"));
        try {
          out.write(room.roomNo + ";" + roomEnSuite + ";" + roomBooking + ";" + roomNights + ";" + roomBooker + "/n");
        }
        finally {
          out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This should be a solution without using external API.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use ObjectOutPutStream to save all ArrayList**

and can be read (reconstituted) using an ObjectInputStream. Persistent storage of objects can be accomplished by using a file for the stream. I

Comment: Yes, but you should make `Room` class implement `Serializable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
abstract class Room
{
    public Room(int newRoomNo, boolean newRoomEnSuite, int newRoomNights, String newRoomBooker)
    {
        // ..
    }

    /* Each implementation of Room must be able to convert itself 
       into a line of text */
    @Override
    public abstract String toString();
}

class RoomWriter
{
    public void write(List<Room> rooms, File file) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        try
        {
            for (Room room : rooms)
            {
                writer.write(room.toString());
                writer.write("\n");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            writer.close();
        }
    }

}
```