# Taking an ArrayList and putting in into a text file

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, text-files

Having some issues with my program I am trying to write.  Basically what I am needing to do is taking an `ArrayList` that I have and export the information to a text file.  I have tried several different solutions from Google, but none have given me any success.

Basically I have two `ArrayList`, two lists, one of graduates and one of undergraduates.  I simply need to take the information that is associated with these `ArrayList` and put them into one text file.

I'll later need to do the opposite (import) the `.txt` file into `ArrayList`, but I can figure that out later.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to say what format the information needs to be in the text file.  Or if you don't care, then say that.  You also need to say how "graduates" and "undergraduates" are represented.  Are they simple strings?   Are they custom classes?  Are they something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing arraylist to textfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566088/writing-arraylist-to-textfile)

Comment: What are the solutions you found using google, and how have they failed?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write the data in a specific format, you could use a `PrintWriter` to write the data to a file in whatever manner you wish. The problem with this is that you will then have to figure out a way in which you will then re-read the text file and populate the data.

On the other hand, you could use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)(tutorial [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)) to write your files as XML. This will provide you with a human readable text file (as above) however, it will be much easier to re-read the text file when populating the data.

Lastly, you could use the [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to write the data and the [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to re-read it back. Note however, that this method does not yield a human readable text file. Also, your classes will need to implement the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [Apache commons-io library](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```
//Put all data into one big list, prepended with size of first list
List<String> allData = new ArrayList<String>(1+grads.size()+undergrads.size());
allData.add(String.valueOf(grads.size());
allData.addAll(grads);
allData.addAll(undergrads);
FileUtils.writeLines(new File("list.txt"), allData);
```

To read the data back:

```
List<String> allData = FileUtils.readLines(new File("list.txt"));
int gradsSize = Integer.parseInt(allData.get(0));
List<String> grads = allData.subList(1, gradsSize+1);
List<String> undergrads = allData.subList(1+gradsSize, allData.size());
```